# Static Array Adapter in Fragment. Good or bad practice?

Tags: android, memory, static, fragment, android-arrayadapter

I've ton a ton of Google searches on static objects in Java and I think I understand how they work in Android. Static objects are GC'ed when the process of the app is terminated, not when the Activity that declares the static object is destroyed (correct me if I'm wrong). I have an app with a Tabhost that uses Fragments in it. The Fragment that declares the object is all the way to the right (there are three Fragments) of the ViewPager. The tab on the right has a ListView that displays user data and I would like that data to persist when the user swipes through all of the tabs or navigates away from the app. This data does not need to be saved, it just needs to remain in memory through normal use of the app. The fix that gives me the result I want is by setting a static prefix to my Array Adapter. My question is, is this considered good practice? I know that using static objects incorrectly can lead to memory issues however I didn't get any FC's with extensive use (landscape to portrait over and over, swiping quickly through the tabs, adding a lot of data to the ListView etc.). Here is the code that I am using

```
static ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,
            container, false);      

        if (personList == null)
        {

            personList = new ArrayList<String>();

        }


        if (arrayAdapter == null)
        {

            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, personList);

        }
```

EDIT:

This is how I am implementing this idea. I have this code in my main Activity (the one that parents the tab fragments. I put this code in the onDestroy() method of the activity to try and reclaim some memory.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (arrayAdapter != null)
    {

        arrayAdapter.clear();

        arrayAdapter = null;

        Log.i("Activity", "Adapter nulled!");

    }


    Log.i("Activity", "Activityhas been destroyed");
}

public ArrayAdapter<String> getArrayAdapter(ArrayList<String> personList)
{

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, personList);

    Log.i("Activity", "Adapter Created");


    return arrayAdapter;
}
```

With this code in my Fragment

```
if (personList == null)
{

    personList = new ArrayList<String>();

}


if (arrayAdapter == null)
{

    arrayAdapter = ((ActivityMainScreen)getActivity()).getArrayAdapter(personList);

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember! Anything that consumes reference to your activity `Context` and is marked as *STATIC* is prone to memory leaks. It is highly not recommended. You may use some sort of **Observer/Observable** pattern to keep your data available in other classes or simple access the required objects via public methods defined in your TabHost activity.

For more info, read this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Regarding memory leaks, perhaps you should test your current implementation on a low-end device because new model devices are pretty rich in terms of resources.

---

**Your Activity:**

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = null;

//initialize your adapter in onCreate

public ArrayAdapter<String> getListAdapter(){
    return arrayAdapter;
}
```

**Your Fragment:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = ((YourActivityClass) getActivity()).getListAdapter();
    yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was thinking about putting the Array Adapter in my Tab host Activity because then it would have the lifespan that I want it to. I just don't know how I can get that object from my Fragment class.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. Does the code look good to you?

Comment: Like I said, setting adapters/views as Static is not a good idea. Look at my updated answer. I'm giving you an example to cast getActivity() into your Activity class and call the desired method defined in that class. Doing so will set your adapter free from Static

Comment: Sweet thanks for all of your help you really helped me out here. I hope you have a great day!

Comment: @Waqas but is it ok to use `static` references when we explicitly `nulling` its *reference* (most probably in onDestroy())?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar It is fine to use static reference as long as you know what you are doing and you can set it to null at the end. But as a good design approach, try not to use static for such instances. Moreover, its not guaranteed that onDestroy will be called each time your activity is destroyed i.e. if the framework kills an activity due to low memory issues then onDestroy won't be called.

Comment: @Waqas is it possible that an activity which is in **foreground** can be killed due to low memory??

Comment: not really. but it will certainly kill the ones in background

Comment: and if an activity process is finished forcefully by the framework due to any reason then which method of life cycle get called?? or is the life cycle of activity is neglected in such scenario?

Comment: yeah the **background** thing can even hurt! thanks for your help i really appreciate

Comment: if you open an activity and press home-key, the onPause and onStop method will be called. But afterwards, if the phone experience low memory then it will start killing background activities and in that case your activity which was in stop state will not call onDestroy because it is forcefully killed by the android system.